# How do I get additional columns from ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY-enabled aggregation?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

The task is to get the maximum of `s_stunde` for each `s_tag`. Easy as that:

```
SELECT s_tag, max(s_stunde) AS letzte_stunde
FROM tstundenplan
GROUP BY s_tag;
```

Works just fine.

```
+-------+---------------+
| s_tag | letzte_stunde |
+-------+---------------+
|     1 |            16 |
|     2 |            16 |
|     3 |            16 |
|     4 |            16 |
|     5 |            16 |
|     6 |             7 |
+-------+---------------+
```

But I'd like to get additional columns from the row with the aggregated `letzte_stunde` field. With `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled, my result looks like this:

```
+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
| s_tag | s_lehrer | s_klasse | letzte_stunde |
+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
|     1 | FM       | 4AHIF    |            16 |
|     2 | PUH      | 2BHIF    |            16 |
|     3 | PUH      | 2BHIF    |            16 |
|     4 | NAI      | 5AHIF    |            16 |
|     5 | PUH      | 2BHIF    |            16 |
|     6 | AT       | 1AHKUI   |             7 |
+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

I do see the logical issue that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` fixes (*as there might be multiple columns that match the aggregated value*), but what's the best way to accomplish the same result with the rule enabled?

Now I know I could use `any_value` to explicitly tell it to use any of the matched values (which can only be one in my case anyway), but it kinda feels like a hack.

You might say that this is a duplicate of [How to make group by work by specifying a single column name in GROUP BY with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162770/how-to-make-group-by-work-by-specifying-a-single-column-name-in-group-by-with-on), but there the aggregation is processed on the primary key, which isn't the case here.

[SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) doesn't answer my question either as it doesn't deal with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

I hope to get an answer soon - thanks!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand. I thought you wanted to get other columns from the row with `MAX(s_stunde)`. This has nothing to do with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, it's just normal SQL.

Comment: Yeah, indeed do I want to do that, but without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, it works. And in the linked question, the query groups by the ID, which would completely break my query. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here)

Comment: You can group by whatever you want, the principle is the same. When you use those methods, `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is irrelevant, because you're not selecting any extra columns in the grouped query.

Comment: Uhm, if I group by the ID, I'll get a row for every single ID, right? That's not what I want...

Comment: Don't group by id, group by `s_tag`, and then join on that column.

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/jrzJtLPc

Comment: Thanks so much. I actually had this before, but I forgot to add one condition (because I misunderstood my task at first) and wondered why there were multiple entries.